# In atlas mongodb, I can't assign object from collection X to an array of object from collection Y

Tags: node.js, mongodb, triggers, mongodb-atlas, mongoose-populate

my goal by using the trigger is :
when X is added from an external source to the mongodb X Collection
it should be pushed to the array of Xs under Y collection

here is the code I tried in the trigger function

```
exports = async function(changeEvent) {
  // A Database Trigger will always call a function with a changeEvent.
  // Documentation on ChangeEvents: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/change-events/

  // This sample function will listen for events and replicate them to a collection in a different Database

  // Access the _id of the changed document:
  const docId = changeEvent.documentKey._id;
  // Get the MongoDB service you want to use (see "Linked Data Sources" tab)
  // Note: In Atlas Triggers, the service name is defaulted to the cluster name.
  const serviceName = "Cluster0";
  const database = "dbName";
  const collection = context.services.get(serviceName).db(database).collection(changeEvent.ns.coll);
  const YCollection = context.services.get(serviceName).db(database).collection("YCollection");

  // Get the "FullDocument" present in the Insert/Replace/Update ChangeEvents
  try {
    console.log(docId)
    // If this is a "delete" event, delete the document in the other collection
    if (changeEvent.operationType === "delete") {
      await collection.deleteOne({"_id": docId});
    }

    // If this is an "insert" event, insert the document into the other collection
    else if (changeEvent.operationType === "insert") {
      const Y = await YCollection.findOne({"serialNumber":changeEvent.fullDocument.deviceId});
      Y.Xs.push(changeEvent.fullDocument);
      await YCollection.replaceOne({"_id": Y._id}, Y);
    }

    // If this is an "update" or "replace" event, then replace the document in the other collection
    else if (changeEvent.operationType === "update" || changeEvent.operationType === "replace") {
      await collection.replaceOne({"_id": docId}, changeEvent.fullDocument);
    }
  } catch(err) {
    console.log("error performing mongodb write: ", err.message);
  }
};
```

### my goal here is to get an array of objectIds in Xs
but instead I get the full document.
so I can't get data from the backend (node) using populate method this way

when I log "changeEvent.fullDocument._id" I get the id, so there should be no problem with the document.

---

I tried

- Y.Xs.push(changeEvent.fullDocument); // the collection gets the full document and it doesn't work with the populate methode
- Y.Xs.push( {
  "$oid":changeEvent.fullDocument._id})
  // the collection get nothing, no response from the populate
- Y.Xs.push(changeEvent.fullDocument._id);  // the collection get nothing, didn't work with the populate

---

I tried installing "mongoose" dependencies
and tried this

var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectId;
new ObjectId("$stringID")
but still didn't work
I get this error

```
> ran at Tue Sep 12 2023 15:02:27 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)
> took 311.111218ms
> error: 
MongoDB Node.js Driver is not supported. Please visit our Atlas App Services documentation.
> trace: 
FunctionError: MongoDB Node.js Driver is not supported. Please visit our Atlas App Services documentation.
    at require (native)
    at function.js:3:16(6)
    at <eval>:12:8(5)
    at <eval>:2:15(7)
    at native
```